# jquery .on not work

Tags: jquery, html

In my DOM this is generated dynamically:

```
<li>333107 (<span id="pos_3488">1</span>)
<span><a id="del_3488" href="#" id_mod="3488"> - </a></span></li>
```

My jQuery code:

```
$("a[id^='del_']").on("click", function(e){
    var id_modelo   = $(this).attr("id_mod");
    var id_bloque   = $(this).parent().attr("id");
});
```

But when you click on the HTML element, there is no call to the "click event".

Comment: any errors in your browser console?

Comment: your script just set the variables, nothing else. What are you expecting it to do?

Comment: write an alert or console.log to verify if it is actually being called... you are just setting variable within your click event handler

Comment: Your code is working fine, you don't see nothing on webpage because of your code just set values to variables. If you put alert or log the values to console you will find that your code is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will helps you.

If you load data dynamically than you have use

- `$(document).on("click",...)`
- also you made mistake in this line too. it was `'a [id^=del_]'`.

```js
$(document).on("click",'a[id^=del_]', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var id_modelo   = $(this).attr("id_mod");
    var id_bloque   = $(this).parent().siblings("span").attr("id");
    console.log(id_modelo);
    console.log(id_bloque);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li>333107 (<span id="pos_3488">1</span>)
<span><a id="del_3488" href="#" id_mod="3488"> - </a></span></li>
```

Answer (score 1):

On this cases I hardly recommend the pattern "event delegation"
https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

This is the solution in your code:

```
$(document).on("click", "a[id^='del_']", function(e) {
  var id_modelo   = $(this).attr("id_mod");
  var id_bloque   = $(this).parent().attr("id");
});
```

The event should be assigned to a constant DOM element, in this case I'm using document but you can change it for another one.

Event delegation is the root solution for this kind of problems, frameworks as angular, react, vuejs used this pattern as a performance solution because they change the DOM often.

Answer (score -1):

Are you making sure the html has generated before you add your listeners? The code below seems to be working. It's probably a race condition issue. Maybe set a `timeout`. Before you add the listeners.

```js
$(function(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    $("a[id^='del_']").on("click", function(e){
        var id_modelo   = $(this).attr("id_mod");
        var id_bloque   = $(this).parent().attr("id");
        console.log("hit:", id_modelo);
    });
  }, 2000); //Wait 2 seconds before setting the event listener
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li>333107 (<span id="pos_3488">1</span>)
  <span><a id="del_3488" href="#" id_mod="3488"> - </a></span></li>
</ul>
```